# Texmaker magic comment

Tags: texmaker, comments, magic-comment

Is there any similar magic comment in `Texmaker` like those in `Texstudio`?
Example:`% !TeX program = xelatex`

Answer (score 6):

No,  When you check the TeXmaker manual there is no such command options. And when you check the issues forum, there has been not request for that feature. TeXmaker and TeXstudio are now targeted at two very different user audiences. When I taught "Technical Writing using LaTeX" to college freshman math majors, I required they use TeXmaker because of the stability, the limited number of extra options, good documentation, and multiplatform support. During the class I demonstrated at least 6 other IDEs during the semester, but I only directly supported TeXmaker.  (July 21,2015 comment converted to answer by RMS)